# DocuSign API fails when RestSharp is updated to 106.10.1

Tags: dll, nuget, docusignapi, restsharp

If I use an API I've written using the DocuSign API in a project with RestSharp updated to 106.10.1, I get the following error:

`System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

However, if I downgrade the RestSharp API to 106.6.10 (the version currently in use in the project where I will eventually use this API) it works fine.  DocuSign's API indicates RestSharp >= 106.3.1.  This couldn't be an alphabetical issue, could it?  (10 < 3 alphabetically) Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Mike, we're looking into this. In the interim, you may need to use the downgraded version of RestSharp

Answer (score 3):

[Dependency Issues with Docusign.Esign.dll's inherit RestSharp Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281028/dependency-issues-with-docusign-esign-dlls-inherit-restsharp-dependency) may offer a workaround that should help.
I still feel we need to look into this on our end. I'll update this thread when I have more info.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Is it possible it's an issue with RestSharp that's marking it as 106.0.0.0?

Also, would it be possible for me to reach out to you for a general question?  Not sure it's SO-worthy, but I would love a little feedback/guidance on our general DocuSign API approach.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: it's all possible (both). I'm at inbar.gazit@docusign.com if you need anything

Answer (score 0):

Another version of the [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/) is out that fixes this issue. Please check latest version 4.4.1